# Translate 'Hide Menu' in navigation menu

Tags: translation

(version 5.18.4 - Joomla with multilingual Dutch)
I didn't get the text 'Hide Menu' in the navigation menu translated. I think it must be not only in the common-base.po but also in the menu.po.
I have added it in a copy from Transifex and it worked on my site.

Comment: Hello HanV. I'm not clear what your question is. Could you explain?

Comment: I think that i did my post on the wrong site. I used the last time, some time ago, the old site with jira, and this site is more for questions than for issues. For issues the right site wil be: lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues (gitlab)